# No module named bcrypt

Tags: python, python-2.7, bcrypt

Does Python version 2.7 have bcrypt in its library?

I tried `import bcrypt` and got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "register.py", line 7, in <module>
    import bcrypt
ImportError: No module named bcrypt
```

Comment: What precisely do you mean by *"support"*? If you mean *"Is there a bcrypt module in the standard library?"*, then no (see [the library reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/index.html)). If you were trying to import [this third-party implementation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bcrypt), whose docs say it *is* compatible with 2.7, have you *installed* it?

Comment: It's not a standard lib in Python 2 nor 3 BTW.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

bcrypt is available as a [pip package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bcrypt/3.1.4) for python 2.7, so yes, it supports python 2.7.

It does not come by default with your python installation though, you need to `pip install bcrypt` in your python environment to `import bcrypt` successfully

Comment: Thank you for the information, re-installing solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

As jonsharpe mentioned, bcrypt is not in standard python library, but it can be easily installed and used in python 2.7

From terminal, just try

```
sudo pip install bcrypt
```

And you should be able to do

```
import bcrypt
```

without issue.

Comment: I installed the module using  sudo pip install bcrypt and inspite of that got the error.But let me try to install again and check

Comment: Thank you for the information, re-installing solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

The following error for me was caused by an upgrade in the version of python.

There are two ways to fix, you can downgrade to the old version of python or you can purge that old version by running the following commands.

sudo apt-get clean

&&
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge

&&
sudo apt-get remove python

&&

sudo apt-get autoremove

Then create a virtualenv with the new python version and install your dependencies. All the best!